# How do you pass/bind a value through a RaisedButton in Flutter?

Tags: listview, button, parameters, parameter-passing, flutter

I have a ListView of RaisedButtons, where each RaisedButton looks like this. The `name` variable is different for each RaisedButton:

```
  new RaisedButton(
      onPressed: _navigateToRoute,
      child: new Text(name),
  ),
```

Tapping on a RaisedButton calls _navigateToRoute():

```
  void _navigateToRoute() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          body: new Text('A value with the word "Hello" should go here'),
        );
      },
    ));
  }
```

When a specific RaisedButton is tapped (e.g. let's say we tap the first RaisedButton in the ListView, where `name = 'Hello'`), I would like to pass the `name` variable to the new route. How do I do that? Is there a way to store `name` in the `context` variable? Should I use another widget instead of RaisedButton?

I could use a [Named Navigator Route](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html) but I don't want to hardcode a route for each item in my ListView.

I found [this Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7877), and I'm not sure if it's the same thing I'm encountering.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can pass the name as an input to the onPressed function. I.e.

```
  new RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => _navigateToRoute(name),
      child: new Text(name),
  ),
```

The function signature would then be:

```
  void _navigateToRoute(String name)
```

Comment: I wanted to stress the `() =>` part is essential. Otherwise your method will get called immediately during build.

Answer (score 7):

You can just pass any variable to a method:

```
new RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () => _navigateToRoute(name),
  child: new Text(name),
),
```

As long as you define your method to be able to receive variable. Than you can do what ever you want with that variable.

```
void _navigateToRoute(String name) {
  Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
        body: new Text(name),
      );
    },
  ));
}
```

You could even pass it further down in your class hierarchy:

```
void _navigateToRoute(String name) {
  Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new MyNewPage(name);
    },
  ));
}

class MyNewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  String name;
  MyNewPage(this.name);

  ...rest of the widget code
}
```